# Obtain a new object with unique pair (key:value) from another object with Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I have some data listing teachers, subjects and students. I want to create a table with subjects associated with teachers where there must not be any repeating pair, but there might be a repeated teacher or repeated subject if the associated pair is not the same. This would be the data:

```
const data =
[
    {
        "teacher": "John Doe",
        "subject": "Maths",
        "student": "student1"
    },
    {
        "teacher": "John Doe",
        "subject": "Maths",
        "student": "student2"
    },
    {
        "teacher": "John Doe",
        "subject": "Art",
        "student": "student1"
    },
    {
        "teacher": "Robert Wilson",
        "subject": "History",
        "student": "student1"
    },
    {
        "teacher": "John Doe",
        "subject": "Music",
        "student": "student1"
    },
    {
        "teacher": "Mark Smith",
        "subject": "Maths",
        "student": "student2"
    },
    {
        "teacher": "Mary Martin",
        "subject": "Science",
        "student": "student1"
    },
    {
        "teacher": "Mary Martin",
        "subject": "Spanish",
        "student": "student1"
    },
    {
        "teacher": "Paula Wilson",
        "subject": "Band",
        "student": "student1"
    },
    {
        "teacher": "Mark Smith",
        "subject": "Band",
        "student": "student2"
    }
]
```

I have tried using the following code:

```
var subjectDict = {}
    data.forEach (x => {
        subjectDict [x.subject] = x.teacher
    })

    var teacherRow = Object.values (subjectDict)
    var subjects = Object.keys (subjectDict)
```

However the output is not accurate because it gives me each subject just once even though it is taught by two different teachers (Band or Maths should appear twice associated with different teachers).

I have created a jsfiddle with the thing that I have tried:

https://jsfiddle.net/soleuil/f2r70Lte/1/

The solution should give me a table where the first row should be filled with the first element, and the last row should be filled with the second element (considering that the order can be different):

```
First Row : Second Row
"Maths":"John Doe"
"Art":"John Doe"
"History":"Robert Wilson"
"Music":"John Doe"
"Maths":"Mark Smith"
"Science":"Mary Martin"
"Spanish": "Mary Martin"
"Band":"Paula Wilson"
"Band":"Mark Smith"
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: a key should be unique in an object

Comment: Ok. How could I approach this then? I don't know how to obtain the desired output.

Comment: It is impossible to obtain this desired output, you'll need to change the format. Eg. making the object values arrays.

Comment: the desired output is not valid json. if you want to store all teachers of each subject, you can use arrays as values

Comment: How will you be using/consuming this final output?

Comment: FWIW a set key/value pairs is often called a Dictionary when they are unique keys (the result here is not)

Comment: @MajedBadawi - nothing here says "JSON" which is a string - the example output is a valid JavaScript object if it is given a name...

Comment: I am creating a table with autotable and jspdf to list every teacher teaching a subject so they can sign in the table. I don't need it to be in the object format as long as I can get the autotable to list each teacher with its subject. I have tried with the dictionary because I am not an expert and I don't know how to get it done.

Comment: The OP needs to choose/decide by which key of the original array's data items the new format has to be grouped, either by `subject` with a list/array of teachers or by `teacher` with a list of subjects .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const data = [ { "teacher": "John Doe", "subject": "Maths", "student": "student1" }, { "teacher": "John Doe", "subject": "Maths", "student": "student2" }, { "teacher": "John Doe", "subject": "Art", "student": "student1" }, { "teacher": "Robert Wilson", "subject": "History", "student": "student1" }, { "teacher": "John Doe", "subject": "Music", "student": "student1" }, { "teacher": "Mark Smith", "subject": "Maths", "student": "student2" }, { "teacher": "Mary Martin", "subject": "Science", "student": "student1" }, { "teacher": "Mary Martin", "subject": "Spanish", "student": "student1" }, { "teacher": "Paula Wilson", "subject": "Band", "student": "student1" }, { "teacher": "Mark Smith", "subject": "Band", "student": "student2" } ];

const [subjects, teachers] = data.reduce(([subjects, teachers], { subject, teacher }) => {
  const subjectIndex = subjects.indexOf(subject);
  const exists = subjectIndex >= 0 && teachers[subjectIndex] === teacher;
  return exists 
    ? [subjects, teachers] 
    : [ [...subjects, subject], [...teachers, teacher] ];
}, [ [], [] ]);

console.log(subjects);
console.log(teachers);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This looks promising but I don't know how could I take this to fill out a table with autotable. So far I created each row selecting the "Object.keys" and "Object.values", but with this solution some of the values are arrays so I would need a key to repeat for each of the values in the string.

Comment: @petoma your use case is not very clear. perhaps you can provide an illustration or rethink the expected output's schema

Comment: I have updated the question including a jsfiddle and more information about what I am looking for.

Comment: @petoma i updated the answer, is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Hey! That is exactly what I was looking for. It works just perfect. I need to learn how to use that method as I believe I am going to need it. Thank you so much. I already maked it as the right answer and as useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the subject as a key with an array of associated teachers with the output:

```
{
  "Maths": [ "John Doe", "Mark Smith" ],
  "Art": [ "John Doe" ],
  "History": [ "Robert Wilson" ],
  "Music": [ "John Doe" ],
  "Science": [ "Mary Martin" ],
  "Spanish": [ "Mary Martin" ],
  "Band": [ "Paula Wilson", "Mark Smith" ]
}
```

```js
const data = [ { "teacher": "John Doe", "subject": "Maths", "student": "student1" }, { "teacher": "John Doe", "subject": "Maths", "student": "student2" }, { "teacher": "John Doe", "subject": "Art", "student": "student1" }, { "teacher": "Robert Wilson", "subject": "History", "student": "student1" }, { "teacher": "John Doe", "subject": "Music", "student": "student1" }, { "teacher": "Mark Smith", "subject": "Maths", "student": "student2" }, { "teacher": "Mary Martin", "subject": "Science", "student": "student1" }, { "teacher": "Mary Martin", "subject": "Spanish", "student": "student1" }, { "teacher": "Paula Wilson", "subject": "Band", "student": "student1" }, { "teacher": "Mark Smith", "subject": "Band", "student": "student2" } ];

let subject_teachers = data.reduce((b, a) => {
  if (!b[a.subject]) b[a.subject] = [];
  if (b[a.subject].indexOf(a.teacher) == -1) b[a.subject].push(a.teacher);
  return b;
}, {})
console.log(subject_teachers)
```

Comment: This fails on the `"teacher": "Mark Smith", "subject": "Maths",` value

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss - It's populating that teacher in the array, so I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: The OP's example output had two pairs, not an array of teachers  (a bit picky on my part yes); that being said this MAY be better for the OP's use - or it could be an array to wrap it also rather than an object STILL a viable example here, just pointing out the OP's example output difference

Answer (score -1):

Based on your desired output, I would slightly modify your code to return an array of objects.

```js
const data =
[
    {
        "teacher": "John Doe",
        "subject": "Maths",
        "student": "student1"
    },
    {
        "teacher": "John Doe",
        "subject": "Maths",
        "student": "student2"
    },
    {
        "teacher": "John Doe",
        "subject": "Art",
        "student": "student1"
    },
    {
        "teacher": "Robert Wilson",
        "subject": "History",
        "student": "student1"
    },
    {
        "teacher": "John Doe",
        "subject": "Music",
        "student": "student1"
    },
    {
        "teacher": "Mark Smith",
        "subject": "Maths",
        "student": "student2"
    },
    {
        "teacher": "Mary Martin",
        "subject": "Science",
        "student": "student1"
    },
    {
        "teacher": "Mary Martin",
        "subject": "Spanish",
        "student": "student1"
    },
    {
        "teacher": "Paula Wilson",
        "subject": "Band",
        "student": "student1"
    },
    {
        "teacher": "Mark Smith",
        "subject": "Band",
        "student": "student2"
    }
];
var subjectDict = data.map (function(x) {
       temp = {};
       temp[x.subject] = x.teacher;
       return temp;
    });
    console.log(subjectDict);
```

Comment: Perhaps update as a "runnable" snippet example using the OP's data